# Unusual MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: c#, .net-4.6.1

I upgraded a third party library (reverting did not fix the error) and now my project has a Resource Exception at runtime.  I have checked the namespace of the library in question and checked that the culture\lib.resource.dll file is there and I have checked that the culture of the project is in fact the culture I expect it to be but this error keeps coming up.  How can I debug this?  How can I find out where .Net is searching for my resource file?

**Update #1**

Error:

```
Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified 
culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "My.Library.MyType.resources" 
was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "My.Library" at compile 
time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and 
fully signed.
```

Stacktrace:

```
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
```

**Update #2**

So it appears that for some reason the resource manager is trying to look for a specific resource file per-type instead of per library.

So instead of searching for MyLibrary.resources, which exists inside my en-us localized folder, it is seaching for MyLibrary.SpecificType.resources which does not exist.  I have another library in the same project which does not have this issue and I can't find any difference between the two that would cause this.  How can this be debugged?

**Update #3**

Ok, so I finally gave up and decided to debug the framework code and I am completely baffled by what is going on under the covers, here is the code that seems to be causing the problem, from resourcemanager.cs:

```
647   // WARNING: This function must be kept in sync with ResourceFallbackManager.GetEnumerator()
648    // Return the first ResourceSet, based on the first culture ResourceFallbackManager would return
648    internal ResourceSet GetFirstResourceSet(CultureInfo culture)
650    {
651        // Logic from ResourceFallbackManager.GetEnumerator()
652        if (_neutralResourcesCulture != null && culture.Name == _neutralResourcesCulture.Name) 
653        {
654            culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
655        }
656
657        if(_lastUsedResourceCache != null) {
658            lock (_lastUsedResourceCache) {
659                if (culture.Name == _lastUsedResourceCache.lastCultureName)
660                    return _lastUsedResourceCache.lastResourceSet;
661            }
662        }
```

So on line 652, culture.Name is "en-US" when I inspect it.  Then without any apparent context switches, on line 659, culture.Name is EMPTY STRING.  WHAT ?!?!

How is this possible?  After that everything seems to be logical since the culture specific resources are not loaded.  But how on earth do we go from a Culture "en-US" to Empty String without any code that assigns a value in between?

**Update #4**

Ok, so by process of elimination, the code MUST have gone into line 654.  The debugger had skipped over the if block so I assumed that it wasn't executed (and you know what they say about assumptions).  However trying to set a breakpoint on that line causes a breakpoint binding error.  I don't know how to fix that, however why would the resource manager reset your culture to invariant when you specified a culture explicitly?  I'm very confused here.  Also on line 659 there is a comparison between 'empty string' and null, from all my previous c# experience this should be false and yet line 660 is executed ?!?!

**Update #5**

Ok, perhaps it's worth mentioning that I am using PRISM 4.  The missing resource error is happening when the code within a Module attempts to load localized resources contained within the same dll as the module.  As a test, I created a dummy enumeration with some localized resources associated with it in another library.  Everything about how I created, configured and loaded the resource was exactly the same as those enumerations inside my module and as long as the resource is in a different dll, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

So very strange result.  It seems this error was happening because I did not have resource files defined for the 'neutral' culture.  So I did not have SomeType.resx, I only had SomeType.en-us.resx.  This seems to have worked in net40 but what I forgot was that when I upgraded one of my nuget packages, I also upgraded the dotNet version at the same time to .net 4.6.1.  When I renamed all the resource files to be SomeType.resx, everything went back to normal.